# Mask sensitive data in a JSON request using logback

Tags: regex, spring, logback, spring-logback

I am trying to mask a JSON request using Logback pattern layout. Please consider the following JSON snippet.

```
{"menu": {
  "account": {
    "name": "amal",
    "saving": [
      {"key": "id", "value": "12345678"},
      {"key": "Open", "value": "OpenDoc"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

Can someone help me write a regex expression to mask {"key": "id", "value": "to be masked"} and mask it as {"key": "id", "value": "**********"}?
I can mask attributes without new lines  with
`<maskPattern>\"name\"\s*:\s*\"(.*?)\"</maskPattern>`. This pattern works for `"name":"****"`. The JSON after masking should look like

```
{"menu": {
  "account": {
    "name": "****",
    "saving": [
      {"key": "id", "value": "********"},
      {"key": "Open", "value": "OpenDoc"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/logback-mask-sensitive-data

Comment: If it works for name, then perhaps like `(?:\"name\"|\"key\":\s*\"id\",\s*\"value\")\s*:\s*\"(.*?)\"` https://regex101.com/r/Vc0t9F/1

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird it worked with a small change.